# Why doesn't the bitwise Not ever work on copied/pasted strings?

Tags: php

Simple enough to test:

```
echo(~~"Hello World"); //Echos Hello World
echo(~"Hello World"); //Echos �����ߨ����
echo(~"�����ߨ����"); //Echos @B@B@B@B@B W@B@B@B@B
```

Why does it work properly for the two Nots directly on top of each other, but not for the copied and pasted string output?

I'd guess there's probably some data being lost somewhere, but how can I output the data in such a way that if I copy and paste it into code which finds the bitwise Not of it, it will actually work?

This has been bugging me and some others I know for quite a while!

Comment: Could be that the characters aren't supported by the shell or whatever it is that you are using to view them or whatever outputted them incorrectly outputted characters to the console that it couldnt handle as something else

Comment: Please don't consider it as answer but I think � is character that browser cannot shows, and by copying that actually your copying another character , so when you use bitwise on it, result is not the thing you suppose!

Comment: The "~~" works because two NOTS restore the string to its original value. Or to put it another way ( x == ~~x ) is always true.

Comment: @JamesAnderson: Yeah of course, but my question asks why the other doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because the char you see has invalid (non existent) code.

For example `H` code is `72`. `~72` is `-73`.

As long as it is not valid char and cannot be shown - it is shown as a square with question mark. Thus it cannot be translated back, because you cannot copy *char with code -73* (or to be more precise - your notepad or OS cannot do that)

Answer (score 1):

Ascii H is 0100 1000 or character 72, ~H is 1011 0111 or character 183. This is beyond the basic Ascii table of 128.

*Given that PHP does not dictate a specific encoding for strings, the character produced will depend on the code page of your script.*

This might be non-printable character (hence represented by �), which are simply replaced by the symbol � when you copy/paste.

See [Php Strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.details) for more details on the implementation of strings as arrays of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, the problem is that the characters you are trying to echo are non-printable.  You can examine what is going on in the various steps of this script to see what you can do if you do indeed need to store this and retrieve it later.

```
$a = "Hello World";

$b = ~$a;

$chars = unpack("c11chars", $b);
foreach ($chars as $char) {
    echo $char . ' = ' ;
    echo chr($char) . "\n";
}

$out = '';
foreach ($chars as $char) {
        $out .= pack("c", $char);
}
echo ~$out;
```

Output:

```
-73 = ?
-102 = ?
-109 = ?
-109 = ?
-112 = ?
-33 = ?
-88 = ?
-112 = ?
-115 = ?
-109 = ?
-101 = ?
Hello World
```

The `?` are what are echoed for me, since they are non-printable.